# BeanDefinitionParsingException: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee]

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have checked all the questions available on stackoverflow related to this exception, but no one seems exactly same as mine issue.

I am getting following exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee]
```

and my web.xml is as follows

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
```

Comment: @Jens I am not using any junits in my project

Comment: spring shouldn't process your web.xml, but why does it do that? misconfiguration or wrong parameters?

Comment: @MartinBaumgartner I have no clue why is it processing web.xml

Comment: How are you starting your spring context?

Comment: @MartinBaumgartner <context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/*.xml</param-value>
 </context-param>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
web.xml

    <context-param> 
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/*.xml</param-value> 
    </context-param>
```

*.xml includes all files in the WEB-INF folder, including the web.xml.

If you have a single context.xml you can use:

```
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/myContext.xml</param-value>
```

If you have multiple spring configs, you could use springContext*.xml to match all context files starting with "springContext"

```
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/springContext*.xml</param-value>
```

If there is no schema in your context.xml's, you could create a folder in WEB-INF and name it spring.

```
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/*.xml</param-value>
```